# Select only specific range of numbered files in Inno Setup

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I have a problem that I would like to solve in the `[Files]` section. The code below searches for all the files that are in the folder and compiles for my final project, but with that a problem arose. I would like a way to specify a number to select only files with a smaller number for the installer. Just below the code in the files section I give an example of what the folder looks like.

```
[Files]
Source: "S:\Aplicativos\MACD\Conversores\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; \
  Flags: overwritereadonly ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs \
    uninsneveruninstall; \
  Permissions: everyone-modify
```

My folder has these files

```
S:\Aplicativos\MACD\Conversores\   
conv0365.sql  
conv0366.sql  
conv0367.sql  
conv0368.sql  
conv0369.sql  
conv0370.sql  
conv0371.sql  
conv0372.sql  
conv0373.sql  
conv0374.sql  
conv0375.sql  
conv0376.sql  
conv0377.sql  
conv0378.sql  
conv0379.sql  
conv0380.sql  
conv0381.sql  
conv0382.sql
```

Knowing this, I would like to select only files smaller than or equal to `conv0377.sql`. How can I do this in the `[Files]` section?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Use [Inno Setup preprocessor](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/) to implement a custom selection of files:

```
[Files]
#define FileEntry(Source) \
  "Source: " + Source + "; DestDir: {app}" + NewLine

#define ProcessFile(Source, FindResult, FindHandle, Prefix, Suffix, Limit) \
  FindResult \
    ? \
      Local[0] = FindGetFileName(FindHandle), \
      Local[1] = Int(Copy(Local[0], Len(Prefix)+1, Len(Local[0])-Len(Prefix+Suffix))), \
      Local[2] = Source + "\" + Local[0], \
      (Local[1] <= Limit ? FileEntry(Local[2]) : "") + \
      ProcessFile(Source, FindNext(FindHandle), FindHandle, Prefix, Suffix, Limit) \
    : \
      ""

#define FindFiles(Source, Prefix, Suffix, Limit) \
  Local[0] = FindFirst(Source + "\" + Prefix + "*" + Suffix, faAnyFile), \
  ProcessFile(Source, Local[0], Local[0], Prefix, Suffix, Limit)

#emit FindFiles("S:\Applications\MACD\Converters", "conv", ".sql", 377)
```